# How to place a line break after font awesome icon in a list?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a LinkedIn-like menu with buttons formed from icons on top of text but I cannot find a way to insert line breaks in CSS form after my FontAwesome icons. For the rest, my script looks fine for my preference.

Although there's `display:block` in `#sidebar nav ul li` for some reason it doesn't provide with the wanted result and recently I've also tried entering `<br>` as `content` after the icon.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
}
 html {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 *, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: inherit;
}
 body, input, select, textarea {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 16.5pt;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1.5;
}
 .icon {
     text-decoration: none;
     border-bottom: none;
     margin-right: 5px;
     position: relative;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
 .icon:before {
     font-size: 1.75em;
     font-style: normal;
     text-transform: none !important;
}
 ul.icons {
     cursor: default;
     list-style: none;
     padding-left: 0;
}
 ul.icons li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0 0.75em 0 0;
}
 ul.icons li:last-child {
     padding-right: 0;
}
 ul.icons li > a, ul.icons li > span {
     border: 0;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 ul.icons li > a:before, ul.icons li > span:before {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-transform: none !important;
}
 ul.icons li > a .label, ul.icons li > span .label {
     display: none;
}
 ul.menu {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
}
 ul.menu > li {
     border-left: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     display: inline-block;
     line-height: 1;
     margin-left: 1.5em;
     padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}
 ul.menu > li:first-child {
     border-left: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     ul.menu > li {
         border-left: 0;
         display: block;
         line-height: inherit;
         margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
         padding-left: 0;
    }
}
 #sidebar {
     padding: 2.5em 2.5em 0.5em 2.5em ;
     background: #ffffff;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
     cursor: default;
     height: 100vh;
     left: 0;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     position: fixed;
     text-align: right;
     top: 0;
     width: 18em;
     z-index: 10000;
}
 #sidebar > .inner {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     min-height: 100%;
     opacity: 1;
     width: 100%;
}
 body.is-ie #sidebar > .inner {
     height: 100%;
}
 #sidebar nav > ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     white-space: pre: 
}
 #sidebar nav > ul > li {
     margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
     opacity: 1;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
}
 #sidebar nav a {
     border: 0;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
     display: block;
     font-size: 0.6em;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 0.25em;
     line-height: 1.75;
     outline: 0;
     padding: 1.35em 0;
     position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 #sidebar nav a:before, #sidebar nav a:after {
     border-radius: 0.2em;
     bottom: 0;
     content: '';
     height: 0.3em;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
 #sidebar nav a:before {
     background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
 #sidebar nav a:after {
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
     max-width: 0;
}
 #sidebar nav a:hover {
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
 #sidebar nav a.active {
     color: #4267b2;
}
 #sidebar nav a.active:after {
     max-width: 100%;
}
 #sidebar nav a.active span {
     color: #4267b2;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
     #sidebar {
         border-right: 0px;
         border-bottom: 1px solid black;
         height: 3.5em;
         left: 0;
         line-height: 3.5em;
         overflow: hidden;
         padding: 0;
         text-align: center;
         top: 0;
         width: 100%;
    }
     #sidebar > .inner {
         flex-direction: row;
         align-items: stretch;
         height: inherit;
         line-height: inherit;
    }
     #sidebar nav {
         height: inherit;
         line-height: inherit;
    }
     #sidebar nav ul {
         display: -moz-flex;
         display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -ms-flex;
         display: flex;
         height: inherit;
         line-height: inherit;
         margin: 0;
    }
     #sidebar nav ul li {
         display: block;
         height: inherit;
         line-height: inherit;
         margin: 0 0 0 2em;
         padding: 0;
    }
     #sidebar nav a {
         height: inherit;
         line-height: 2em;
    }
     #sidebar nav a:after {
         background-image: none;
         background-color: #4267b2;
    }
     #sidebar nav span:after {
         content: "</br>";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>LinkedIn like menu</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main2.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" />
 </head>
 <body>

  <section id="sidebar">
   <div class="inner">
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#home"><span class="icon fas fa-user"></span>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><span class="icon fas fa-search"></span>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><span class="icon fas fa-phone"></span>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </section>

  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should this be what you want to achieve.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16.5pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.icon:before {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}

ul.icons {
  cursor: default;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.75em 0 0;
}

ul.icons li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

ul.icons li>a,
ul.icons li>span {
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.icons li>a:before,
ul.icons li>span:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}

ul.icons li>a .label,
ul.icons li>span .label {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu>li {
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}

ul.menu>li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.menu>li {
    border-left: 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

#sidebar {
  padding: 2.5em 2.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
  width: 18em;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#sidebar>.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

body.is-ie #sidebar>.inner {
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: pre:
}

#sidebar nav>ul>li {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar nav a {
  border: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  line-height: 1.75;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 1.35em 0;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#sidebar nav a:before,
#sidebar nav a:after {
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 0.3em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar nav a:before {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#sidebar nav a:after {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #003085, #029bde);
  max-width: 0;
}

#sidebar nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#sidebar nav a.active {
  color: #4267b2;
}

#sidebar nav a.active:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#sidebar nav a.active span {
  color: #4267b2;
}

span.icon {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #sidebar {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 3.5em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 3.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #sidebar>.inner {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  #sidebar nav {
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  #sidebar nav ul {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #sidebar nav ul li {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #sidebar nav a {
    height: inherit;
    line-height: 2em;
  }
  #sidebar nav a:after {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #4267b2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>LinkedIn like menu</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main2.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <section id="sidebar">
    <div class="inner">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home"><span class="icon fas fa-user"></span>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><span class="icon fas fa-search"></span>About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"><span class="icon fas fa-phone"></span>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just wrap the home and other texts inside a div ,they'll automatically break down

Comment: That could be useful but it would change every instance regardless of width. In my code I try to introduce it in widths lower than 1280px.